# Facebook permission dialog opens automatically for new visitors at start, asking for basic permissions

Tags: facebook, iframe, permissions, oauth

I have a facebook iframe app, and I have just noticed that a basic permission dialog is fired for every new visitor. This dialog is launched by Facebook, not by my application (index.php hasn't been called yet).

This behavior is new, and not wanted : users are allowed to visit some pages of the app and later are asked for extended permissions.

At first I though it was the new open graph feature, but removing it didn't help. I don't use the new Enhanced Auth Dialog either. I tried turning social discovery on and off also.

Does anyone else has experienced this behavior ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you haven't enabled Authenticated Referrals in your app settings

Comment: You were right ! Thanks !
Turns out putting Enhanced Auth Dialog off didn't disable the authenticated referrals. you have to do disable it before going back to the standard permission dialogs.